# The actual differences between CPU's physical memory and RAM

Tags: memory, cpu

Been looking around for answers but none come out satisfying so far, and very often misleading with mixed-up terminologies. Now here's the thing... Physical Memory is the kind of memory;

i. as seen by the CPU as the final memory on its address bus. That means it has already passed the MMU translation / paging, right?

ii. calculated based on the address bus width. If it is 48-bit wide, than it should be 256TB of physical memory addresses available for the system, right?

Now my question;

If I have 8GB of RAM, how on earth the much larger physical memory addresses generated by the CPU are mapped to the physical RAM? What translation unit is there between the Physical memory and the available RAM? From what I read, physical RAM has already passed the virtual / MMU translation phase.

And no, I am not talking about virtual memory. I am asking about the relationships between the physical memory (the one that appears on the CPU address bus) and the actual physical RAM.

Thanks.

Comment: Or maybe I asked the question the wrong way. I don't know. This is all very confusing to me.

Comment: The CPU includes a memory controller, which speaks with RAM.  RAM itself is not a dumb collection of bits: the memory controller communicates it with several different signalling wires to ask for specific data locations in each chip.  The memory controller will map to different chips, and some addresses will just not be valid.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_dynamic_random-access_memory#SDR_SDRAM gives a high level overview of the signalling for SDRAM.  Current chips are a bit more complex but the ideas are the same.

Comment: Simply put: there is the set of all possible addresses (2^64).  Each of these addresses is directed towards a device (if present) or sinked (if no device responds). The first block of addresses from 0 up to RAM size -1 is steered to the eMC. More RAM means a bigger block. Multi sockets machines are a little more involved (not much more). Other addresses are reclaimed by the IO devices (PCIe root ports, embedded graphics, DMI) and eventually arbitrarily terminated if no device responds to them.